# Why am I getting an error on the makefile.win? (dev c++ 6.3)

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I am using C++,
I'm quite new to programming and wanted to try out some things.

I have been smooth sailing until I reached multifile programming..

I tried putting all the contents of the 3 files into a single cpp file and it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int numOf_people = 4;

struct person
{
    std::string name;
} individual[4]; // 4 identities

void input_movieName (person individual[], int numOf_people)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numOf_people; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter individual " << i+1 << " name : ";
        cin >> individual[i].name;
    }
}

int main()
{
    input_movieName (individual, numOf_people);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numOf_people; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name of person " << i+1 << " : " << individual[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

but these would just not work:

*head.h*

```
#ifndef MAIN
#define MAIN

const int numOf_people = 4;

struct person
{
    std::string name;
} individual[4]; // 4 identities

void input_movieName (person*, int);

#endif
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "head.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    input_movieName (individual, numOf_people);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numOf_people; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name of person " << i+1 << " : " << individual[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

*func.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "head.h"

using namespace std;

void input_movieName (person individual[], int numOf_people)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numOf_people; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter individual " << i+1 << " name : ";
        cin >> individual[i].name;
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error in the makefile.win pointing this error out:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

the error says

"head.h:9: multiple definition of `individual'; head.h:9: first defined here" >I removed the directories but I think you guys get the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you *define* the variable `individual` in the header file:

```
struct person
{
    std::string name;
} individual[4];
```

That means the variable will defined in each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where the header file was included, and C++ only allows variables (and functions) to be defined once.

I suggest you split these into the separate structure definition, and a separate variable *declaration*:

```
struct person
{
    std::string name;
};

extern struct individual[4];
```

Then in a single source file you define the variable:

```
struct individual[4];
```

Comment: I got a bit confused at first but I finally got it !! Thanks a lot ! Just for clarification though, do I need to do that extern for every variable? I mean I tried giving it a simple add function giving int num1 = 2; and int num2 = 3; it gave me the same problems.

Comment: @Secret For variables you need the `extern` part to tell the compiler that you're doing a declaration and not a definition.